# During normal test, execute a parallel def in every instruction

Tags: javascript, cucumber, watir

Let's imagine that I have a normal automated test with Watir and Cucumber that goes to a webpage, does some stuff, and then ends. After every click and every micro-operation I do with the scenario (let's say that a normal step contains several micro-operations), I want to make a check.

The check is look in the Firefox console and look for JavaScript errors (I already have a system for reading the display of the FF console). And I want this check to be done after every action of the automation.

The most increased frequency I have right now is to use:

```
AfterStep do |scenario|
  raise get_js_error_feedback() unless get_js_error_feedback().empty?
end
```

But this is not enough. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, of course, I need something elegant that launches the "check for JS" function, but I dont want to write the call in every function of every method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get more granular, you can use [Selenium-Webdriver's AbstractEventListener](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Support/AbstractEventListener.html).

You can create a listener that performs an action after each click action (and other events):

```
class JavascriptListener < Selenium::WebDriver::Support::AbstractEventListener
  def after_click(element, driver)
    puts 'after_click'
  end
end
```

You then need to pass that listener to the Watir::Browser:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :listener => JavascriptListener.new()
```

When you perform a click action, your code in the `after_click` method will be executed:

```
browser.button.click
#=> 'after_click'
```

I am not sure what is in your `get_js_error_feedback` method. You may or may not need to make some changes to it so that it is available to your listener.